# How to store aws organization unit ID and scp policy ID in variable in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, aws-sdk, boto3

I am working on AWS organization : I have created organizations units(OUs) and policies through python script separately ...Now I want attach created policies to the OUs.

```
   response = client.attach_policy(
         PolicyId=policyID,
         TargetId=OUID
   )
```

I can get the list of policies and OUs which has *organizationalunits-ID* and *Policy-ID*

I tried as below to store value of ID to use in attach_policy but got error :

```
      OUID=str(OUdetails['OrganizationalUnits']['Id'])
      policyID=str(listpolicy['Policies']['Id'])
```

**example of ID
          {'Id': 'ou-uwjh-radcf5d4'}**

**error:**

```
       OUID=str(OUdetails['OrganizationalUnits']['Id'])
       TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

       OUID=int(OUdetails['OrganizationalUnits']['Id'])
       TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Comment: What is the type of `OUdetails`? It seems to be a list and not a dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that `OUID` is being stored as a list and not a dictionary. So when you're trying to access `OUdetails` later, python things you're trying to pull an element from a list, not a dictionary.

Try printing the variable `OUdetails` and see if it shows up as a list or dictionary.

Comment: I tried to print OUdetails. It seems like list of organization unit information.

Comment: Yes, if it's a list then you'll have to first select the list element in question (OUID[0]) then, the dictionary in question.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help
Now I am able to store both values in the variable:

```
                OUdetails = client.list_organizational_units_for_parent(
                      ParentId='', 
                     # NextToken='string',
                     # MaxResults=123 
                   )
                print(OUdetails)

                 for key in OUdetails ['OrganizationalUnits']:
                   ouid=key['Id']
                   print("\033[92m"+"OrganizationUnit's ID"+"\033[0m",ouid)
```